# Do I need Visual Studio Code Insiders to install jupyter Notebook extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter

I run the latest Visual Studio Code (1.56.1 windows 10 professional, as of today) but the jupyter extension file ms-toolsai.jupyter-2021.6.832913620.vsix complains with:

> Unable to install extension 'ms-toolsai.jupyter' as it is not compatible with VS Code '1.56.1'.

How do I find out what is the latest version of jupyter compatible with VSC stable?

Answer (score 1):

The latest compatible build of the Jupyter extension for VS Code 1.56.1 is 2021.6.832593372. v2021.6.832913620 requires VS Code 1.57.0-insider.

Unfortunately the VS Code marketplace doesn't currently indicate which version of VS Code you need to install a specific VSIX. There's a feature request for this: https://github.com/microsoft/vsmarketplace/issues/43. In the meantime it's recommended to install extensions from inside VS Code wherever possible, as VS Code version requirements are correctly resolved from there.

Comment: In my case a firewall doesn't allow connections to the marketplace. I need to install the vsix files manually. A hint on the extensions site would help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Latest version (2021.6.914258744) seems broken, but this one [2021.6.832593372](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/_apis/public/gallery/publishers/ms-toolsai/vsextensions/jupyter/2021.6.832593372/vspackage) works.

**Working setup** as of June 9, 2021 (**full offline install**):

1. VSCode-win32-x64-1.56.2.zip 
   SHA1: 7F9DA2C7A35BA29778ECB36A2D3D81CBCCD3060D
2. ms-toolsai.jupyter-2021.6.832593372.vsix +
   ms-python.python-2021.5.842923320.vsix = **OK** 
    SHA1:
   6D42F2306CCC870619FD058A09AA267FE33792DE
3. ms-toolsai.jupyter-2021.6.914258744.vsix +
   ms-python.python-2021.5.842923320.vsix = **Broken** 
    SHA1:
   EF6FAB40ADB57894D169AD1E5811D19573E2F3C4